# Uniform continuity of $\sin^{10}{x}$

Tags: analysis

> let  $f(x) = sin^{10}{x}$, is this function uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

I just wanna validate my answer, based on the definition of uniform continuity, for any epsilon: we're looking for a delta independent of the choice of x, such that if the distance between 2 points is less than delta, the distance between their images will be smaller than epsilon, and by the periodicity of sin(x), sin(x) = sin(x +$2\pi$), and hence for any epsilon, picking delta= 2$\pi$ does the job, is this enough for proving uniform continuity?

Comment: No...The difference between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is smaller than $2\pi$, but the difference between $\sin(0)$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is $1$. So take any $\epsilon<1$ and it will not work.

Comment: Oh yes, completely missed this, I can prove that the difference $||f(y) -f(x)||$ is bounded by 1, does it follow from this,that picking a delta = epsilon does the job and hence it's uniformly continuous?

Comment: But again, you need the difference to be bounded by $\epsilon$ when $x,y$ are very close points, not just by $1$. What I suggest is to use the formula $z^n-w^n=(z-w)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}w+z^{n-3}w^2+...+zw^{n-2}+w^{n-1})$. Write it for $z=\sin(x), w=\sin(y)$ and $n=10$ and try to see how it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Any continuous periodic function on $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, a $\delta$ that works for this function on the interval $[0, 2p]$ (where $p$ is the period) works for the function on $\mathbb R$.